# How to configure that the user principal added to Kerberos cannot access a specific host principal of realms

Tags: linux, kerberos

I installed Kerberos on CentOS 7 via yum command.

```
yum install krb5-server krb5-libs krb5-workstation pam_krb5 -y
```

My situation is as below:

- There is 1 KDC.
- It has 2 Service Servers.

The KDC's krb5.conf file is set as follows.

```
# Configuration snippets may be placed in this directory as well
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 pkinit_anchors = FILE:/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
 default_realm = MYREALM.NET
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
MYREALM.NET = {
 kdc = kdc.myrealm.net
 admin_server = kdc.myrealm.net
}

[domain_realm]
.myrealm.net = MYREALM.NET
myrealm.net = MYREALM.NET
```

And I added the host principal with the following command.

```
# kadmin.local -q 'addprinc -randkey host/build.myrealm.net'
# kadmin.local -q 'ktadd -k /tmp/build.keytab host/build.myrealm.net'
# scp /tmp/build.keytab build.myrealm.net:/etc/krb5.keytab


# kadmin.local -q 'addprinc -randkey host/api.myrealm.net'
# kadmin.local -q 'ktadd -k /tmp/api.keytab host/api.myrealm.net'
# scp /tmp/api.keytab api.myrealm.net:/etc/krb5.keytab
```

And I added a user principal with the following command.

```
# kadmin.local -q 'addprinc eric'
```

With the user principal added above, the two service servers are successfully connected without a password through the following ssh command.

By the way, I want to manage a service server accessible by user principal.

I am wondering how to set the added user principal not to access a specific host principal of realms.

To summarize, I would like advice on how to make the added user principal `eric` accessible only to `api.myrealm.net` among the service servers.

I added a user principal and a host principal, and copied the host principal keytab file to the service server.

The service server in the same realm is successfully accessed without a password.

However, what I want to do is manage authorization per user principal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to my question, I recommend using FreeIPA.
Creating a policy in FreeIPA, and applying it on a per-user basis, solved my intended problem.

https://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page